# Content filter using button with jquery still doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

hello I want to ask about javascript. I created a content filter feature using a button. First, I want to display the default content 'all'. When I click on the 'tech' category, the content all disappears and only shows 'tech' content. When I click on the 'education' category, the tech content disappears and only displays 'education' content.

I have made the code as below, but it's still not what I want. the problem is, when I click on a category, the old value still appears and each category only displays 1 content.

how do i make the filter I want with jquery or pure JS?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on("click" , function(){
        let target = $(this).data('target');
      let content = $('.list-content').data('content');
      
      console.log(target);
      
      $('#' + target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.list-content{
  display:none;
}

.list-content .show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-tag">
  <button data-target="all">All</button>
  <button data-target="tech">Tech</button>
  <button data-target="industry">Industry</button>
  <button data-target="edu">Education</button>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="list-content" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  
  <div class="list-content" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  
  <div class="list-content" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  
  <div class="list-content" id="edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
  <div class="list-content" id="edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Id should be unique throughout the page.
2. Hide all the lists first to remove old ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.all').show();
    $('button').on("click" , function(){
        let target = $(this).data('target');
      let content = $('.list-content').data('content');
      
      console.log(target);
      
      $('.list-content').hide(); // You should hide all the contents before showing the filtered ones.
      $('.' + target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.list-content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-tag">
  <button data-target="all">All</button>
  <button data-target="tech">Tech</button>
  <button data-target="industry">Industry</button>
  <button data-target="edu">Education</button>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="list-content all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  <div class="list-content all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  <div class="list-content all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  <div class="list-content all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
  
  <div class="list-content tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  <div class="list-content tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  <div class="list-content tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  <div class="list-content tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
  
  <div class="list-content industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  <div class="list-content industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  <div class="list-content industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  <div class="list-content industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
  
  <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
  <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
  <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
  <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, i made mistake, I just want to change my post using class. And how to make the category 'all' for default? from the code you created, all of them disappear. as I explained above, all categories default to display before we click other categories

Comment: Put $('.all').show() underneath the $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: oh i see, so i dont need use if condition for that? thank you bro